# How to iterate over a JSON array in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I have a JSON array:

```
[
    {
        "art": "A",
        "count": "0",
        "name": "name1",
        "ean": "802.0079.127",
        "marker": "null",
        "stammkost": "A",
        "tablename": "IWEO_IWBB_01062015"
    },
    {
        "art": "A",
        "count": "0",
        "name": "2",
        "ean": "657.7406.559",
        "marker": "null",
        "stammkost": "A",
        "tablename": "IWEO_IWBB_02062015"
    }
]
```

To iterate over the array in PHP I would use the following code to iterate over the tablenames:

```
foreach($jArray as $value){ 
  $tablename = $value['tablename'];
  //some code
}
```

How can I do this in Node.js? I found many questions with it, but no actual answer. Most of them are from 2011.

Comment: _JSON_ is just a notation. Convert it into a native _Array_ and then perform the operation as usual, `for(;;)` for an _Array_, `for..in` for an _Object_

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
var tables = [
    { "art":"A","count":"0","name":"name1","ean":"802.0079.127","marker":"null","stammkost":"A","tablename":"IWEO_IWBB_01062015" },
    { "art":"A","count":"0","name":"2","ean":"657.7406.559","marker":"null","stammkost":"A","tablename":"IWEO_IWBB_02062015" }
];

tables.forEach(function(table) {
    var tableName = table.name;
    console.log(tableName);
});
```

Comment: what exactly should print ? I got 'undefined', twice :(

Answer (score 11):

You need to de-serialize it to an object first.

```
var arr = JSON.parse(<your json array>);
for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
{
  var tablename = arr[i].tablename;
}
```

Comment: `for..in` is for looping over keys of _Objects_, you may want to loop using `for` instead

Answer (score 1):

Another way to iterate over Array in node:

```
let Arr = [
    {"art": "A","count": "0","name": "name1","ean": "802.0079.127","marker": "null","stammkost": "A","tablename": "IWEO_IWBB_01062015"},
    {"art": "A","count": "0","name": "2","ean": "657.7406.559","marker": "null","stammkost": "A","tablename": "IWEO_IWBB_02062015"}
];

for (key in Arr) {
  console.log(Arr[key]);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var tables = [
    { "art":"A","count":"0","name":"name1","ean":"802.0079.127","marker":"null","stammkost":"A","tablename":"IWEO_IWBB_01062015" },
    { "art":"A","count":"0","name":"2","ean":"657.7406.559","marker":"null","stammkost":"A","tablename":"IWEO_IWBB_02062015" }
];

tables.map(({name})=> console.log(name))
```

for iterate in js for...in, map, forEach, reduce